# DXA-2.2.5 java how to resolve page url for current Model entity

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2

We are using dxa-2.2.5 Java and we are using `GraphQlLinkresolver`. We want to get url of detail page of Component TCM, how can we achieve it?

On Model class I have tried something like this:

```
public String getUrl(String localizationId){
    LinkResolver linkResolver = new GraphQLLinkResolver();
    return linkResolver.resolveLink(TcmUtils.buildTcmUri(localizationId,getId()),localizationId);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
13:53:39.720 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] ERROR   o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp] - Servlet.service() for servlet
[jsp] threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException: null at
com.sdl.dxa.tridion.linking.GraphQLLinkResolver.resolveComponent(GraphQLLinkResolver.java:28) at
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.linking.AbstractLinkResolver._resolveLink(AbstractLinkResolver.java:69) at
com.sdl.webapp.tridion.linking.AbstractLinkResolver.resolveLink(AbstractLinkResolver.java:35) at
com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.LinkResolver.resolveLink(LinkResolver.java:43)
```

Can someone please advise on this, what is wrong here or suggest me how can I get page url of Component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only give you the answer in .NET (because I haven't worked with DXA Java still), but I'm certain that the same or a very similar approach should be used.

The bigger mistake is that the `resolveLink()` method expects the ID of the Component it's supposed to resolve. In your code, you are giving it the Publication ID.

One other thing which should be avoided is directly newing the `GraphQLLinkResolver` yourself. That way you hardcode the type instead of relying on DI. In .NET you have all the providers available to you from the `SiteConfiguration` class. Now I don't know whether it's called the same in Java, but I expect something similar to exist.

See the attached screenshot for .NET:
[image]

Comment: Hi @Atila, Thanks for you suggestion, problem in my code was i was newing GraphQlLinkResolver, instead of that I Updated that line with
LinkResolver linkResolver = BeanUtil.getBean(LinkResolver.class);

Comment: so now application is taking linkresolver from spring context, Thanks a lot :) .